# Make a .desktop file that runs a command line

Tags: .desktop

Okay so maybe I'm being stupid, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so I'm asking here for help.

I made a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` to create a shortcut for a specific command I usually ran in the terminal. However, no matter how I put it, launching the app doesn't do anything.

Here's the .desktop file I currently have:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Exec=mpv https://iptv-ch.github.io/netplus.m3u
MimeType=application/streamingmedia;application/x-streamingmedia;
Icon=/home/yves/Images/download-icon-television+tv+icon-1320086462225673727_512.png
Terminal=false
Name=Télévision FR
GenericName=Télévision FR
Comment=Accès TV France via IPTV
Categories=AudioVideo;Video;Player;TV;Application;
```

I looked for stackoverflow help and figures that maybe doing `Exec=bash -c 'mpv https://iptv-ch.github.io/netplus.m3u'` instead would work better, but it gave me the exact same results.
Even when I set `Terminal=true`, no terminal opens on launch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you validate it with `desktop-file-validate`? Did you try giving the full path to `mpv`?

Comment: Instead of calling command-line tools `mpv` or `bash`, try calling a windowed application like the terminal itself.  `Exec=gnome-terminal -- mpv https://...`

Comment: `desktop-file-validate` gives no result and I'm not using gnome but I'll look into it